# Quote first two columns in large .csv file

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have a large csv file about 25 million lines and **256** columns. CSV file's field separator is `~` character.

I want to replace first 2 columns data like that

```
From : data1~data2~data3..................................
To   : "data1"~"data2"~data3................................
```

I am using currently `awk` but like this way:

```
cat file | awk -F "~" '{print "\""$1"\"""\""$2"\"~"$3"~"$4"~"...................}'
```

So I am typing 256 columns in awk like `$4"~"$5"~"$6"~".....$256"~"`

Is there any other better way to code it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need specify all 256 fileds, do it as following to changes only first and second columns, then perform `print` with `OFS='~'` and avoid `cat`ing to `awk` while `awk` can read from file as well by itself alone.

```
awk -F'~' '{$1="\""$1"\""; $2="\""$2"\""; print}' OFS='~' infile
```

To have changes on two last fields.

```
awk -F'~' '{$(NF-1)="\""$(NF-1)"\""; $NF="\""$NF"\""; print}' OFS='~' infile
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I did not know this way

Comment: If I want to change last 2 columns, how can I do it  ?

Comment: see my update, please

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` one would typically write

```
sed 's/[^~]*/"&"/;s//"&"/2'
```

But because you mentioned a large file, so this one will probably be **much faster** than the solution above or the `awk` version:

```
sed 's/\(^[^~]*\)~\([^~]*\)/"\1"~"\2"/'
```

Or, maybe easier to read, with extended regular expressions:

```
sed -E 's/(^[^~]*)~([^~]*)/"\1"~"\2"/'
```